# Remove duplicates in combination generated for 3 digits in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

i generated a possible combination of 3 digit series. I wan to remove duplicated values.
[image: Excel Sheet Screenshot]

I am using `=IF(A5="","",CONCATENATE(LEFT(C5,1),RIGHT(C5,1),MID(C5,2,1)))` for generating combination but this is also generating duplicates....as you can see in A6 Row. Can you please guide further to avoid duplication.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Select C5:M5 and enter this as a array formula (commit with `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter`):

```
=IFERROR(SMALL(MMULT({100,10,1},VALUE(MID(A5,CHOOSE(MAX(FREQUENCY(VALUE(MID(A5,{1;2;3},1)),VALUE(MID(A5,{1;2;3},1)))),{1,1,2,2,3,3;2,3,1,3,1,2;3,2,3,1,2,1},{1,1,2;2,3,1;3,2,3},{1;2;3}),1))),{1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5,0,6}),"")
```

Then fill down.

Note that this assumes the entries in column `A` are numbers. The result will be stored as numbers instead of text.